# TableView javafx не отображает

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Нужно с Бд загрузить таблицу в tableView.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn col0;
@FXML
private TableColumn col1;
@FXML
private TableColumn col2;
@FXML
private TableView table;

@FXML
private void initialize(){
                col0.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableList,String>("id"));
                col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableList,String>("subjects"));
                col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ObservableList,String>("hours"));
                table.setItems(DbControl.toObservableList(DbControl.getAllTableFields()));
}
```

Чего не хватает? toObservableList возвращает ObservableList.

Comment: Вы столбцы добавили в таблицу?

Comment: Приложите реализацию класса DbControl